# Gap Finding - Dates

Tags: postgresql-9.5, gaps-and-islands

Essentially i face a islands & gaps problem but unlike many of the examples i found i do not have a unique ID to group over to find my gaps.

Data is timestamp without timezone formatted and an example is the following 10 dates:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    measurement_timestamp timestamp without time zone
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);

INSERT INTO test (measurement_timestamp ) VALUES

'2019-11-14 08:22:00',
'2019-11-14 11:10:00',
'2019-11-14 11:11:00',
'2019-11-14 11:12:00',
'2019-11-14 11:13:00',
'2019-11-14 11:15:00',
'2019-11-14 11:16:00',
'2019-11-14 11:17:00',
'2019-11-14 11:18:00',
'2019-11-14 11:19:00';
```

I need to find the following elements: gap > 1 minute

GAPID (can be any sequential number or ignored if needed) StartDateTime,EndDateTime,Gapsize in minutes

Example:

```
(1,'2019-11-14 08:22:00','2019-11-14 11:10:00', 168)
```

previous questions asked commonly have a grouping based on a member or other but i simply need the gap in a sequence to find my datagaps. Data attached to the date cannot be used for grouping and cannot be shared nor do i really care. i just need to find the gaps > 1 minute.

EDIT:

Im now looking for ISLAND size:

so assuming i have same list as before i now would like the following output:

```
'GAP','2019-11-14 08:22:00','2019-11-14 11:10:00', 168
'ISLAND','2019-11-14 11:10:00','2019-11-14 11:13:00', 3
'GAP','2019-11-14 11:13:00','2019-11-14 11:15:00',2
'ISLAND','2019-11-14 11:15:00','2019-11-14 11:19:00',5
```

can that be done via sql as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first calculate the gap and then use that in a second level to calculate the longest gap (this can't be done in a single statement, as you can't nest window function calls):

```
select *
from (
  select rn, 
         prev_measurement,
         measurement_timestamp,
         gap,
         dense_rank() over (order by gap desc) as rnk
  from (
    select row_number() over w as rn,
           measurement_timestamp,
           lag(measurement_timestamp) over w as prev_measurement,
           measurement_timestamp - lag(measurement_timestamp) over w as gap
    from test
    window w as (order by measurement_timestamp)
  ) t1
  where gap > interval '1 minute'
) t2
where rnk = 1;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2cfa95a59fb5a5ee0ff830e6b5b72114)

Comment: awewsome i can get that gap working indeed.

can i also get the inverse done? show how large the continuous chain is before the gap? (island size)?

aka:
```
island,starttime,endtime,size_in_minutes
gap,starttime,endtime,size_in_minutes
```